# Receiving ActiveX Automation: Bad Index Error Message

Tags: excel, vba, object, vb6

### Prelude

I am starting a new project, and basically I am using Excel as a log for another program I am using. With this being said, this is a mixture of VBA (Only when using Excel's object) and VB6 (the main "host" programming language). *This is why both languages are tagged as I anticipate hateful comments from the use of tags; I am looking for a solution in **either**/**mixture of both** programming languages!!*
Also, I am aware some *VBA activists* will say to never use `ActiveSheet`. I am not concerned about this and I would like to say *thank you* ahead of time. I have one sheet in this workbook as it's primary function is to serve as a log. The `ActiveSheet` will always be the one and only sheet.

---

I have the following code, and I am not too familiar with Setting a workbook as an `object`, which is likely the reason I receive the `Bad Index` error.

```
Sub Test()
    ' Checking if Excel is open, if not, open it.
    Dim xL As Object, wBook As Object, iCloseThings As Byte
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application") 
    On Error GoTo 0
    If xL Is Nothing Then
        iCloseThings = 1   ' Set Excel to close only if it was never open
        Set xL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If

    Set wBook = xL.Workbooks("C:\Users\<UserName>\Documents\<WorkBook>.xlsx").ActiveSheet



    If iCloseThings = 1 Then xL.Quit
End sub
```

What I need assistance with is how would I properly set this object to point to the exact workbook I have in the above example? All I have ever known to do was something such as `Set wBook = XL.Workbooks("<WorkBook>.xlsx").ActiveSheet` because I knew such workbook would already be open. But with the possibility of it not being open, I need something a little more flexible.

Thanks for your assistance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need some different cases handling, mainly depending if the wanted workbook is already open or not should a running Excel session be "caught"

you may want to use some dedicated Functions not to clutter your main code and be more effective in both debugging and maintaining your code, like follows

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
    ' Checking if Excel is open, if not, open it.
    Dim xL As Object, wBook As Object, wSheet As Object, iCloseThings As Byte

    Set xL = GetExcel(iCloseThings)

    Set wBook = GetExcelWorkbook(xL, "C:\Users\<UserName>\Documents\<WorkBook>.xlsx")
    If wBook Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set wSheet = wBook.ActiveSheet

    If iCloseThings = 1 Then xL.Quit
End Sub

Function GetExcel(iCloseThings As Byte) As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetExcel = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If GetExcel Is Nothing Then
        iCloseThings = 1   ' Set Excel to close only if it was never open
        Set GetExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If
End Function

Function GetExcelWorkbook(xL As Object, wbFullName As String) As Object
    Dim wbName As String

    wbName = Right(wbFullName, Len(wbFullName) - InStrRev(wbFullName, "\"))
    On Error Resume Next
    Set GetExcelWorkbook = xL.Workbooks(wbName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If GetExcelWorkbook Is Nothing Then
        Set GetExcelWorkbook = xL.Workbooks.Open(wbFullName)
    Else
        If GetExcelWorkbook.Path & "\" & wbName <> wbFullName Then
            MsgBox "A workbook with the wanted name '" & wbName & "' is already open but its path doesn't match the required one" _
                   & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Close the already open workbook and run this macro again", vbCritical + vbInformation
            Set GetExcelWorkbook = Nothing
        Else
            MsgBox "Wanted workbook is already open", vbInformation
        End If
    End If
End Function
```